# What do you call a word that has multiple senses or parts of speech in one sentence?

Tags: meaning, terminology, ambiguity, parts-of-speech, polysemes

Consider the following sentence.

> John used to work for the **newspaper** that you are reading.

(It has been collected from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy).)

"Newspaper" has several well-known senses.

Newspaper could mean **a company**:

> John used to work for the newspaper.

It could also mean **the physical object**:

> the newspaper that you are reading.

It should be readily apparent that John never worked for that ink-on-died-wood-pulp in front of you.
It should also be clear that you are not reading a company.
In the first sentence, though, the word seems to take both senses at the same time.

@Nigelj provided another example:

> I was going to **dust** but there wasn't any

Here, **dust** is first used as a verb and then as a noun—not only having a different word sense but also being a different part of speech.

I am looking for a name for this occurrence to look it up in a reference book or textbook.
It is of interest to me because it is a case that is often neglected by computational word-sense-disambiguation systems.

Terms that I have considered but are not (to my knowledge) correct for describing this:

- **[polyseme / homonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy)** : a word holding multiple senses at the same time can of-course only occur with words that have multiple senses in the first place. But not all uses of words with multiple senses exhibit the behavior.
- **[Syntactic ambiguity/amphiboly/amphibology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity)**: this sentence is un-ambigious. It only has one interpretation.
- **[Antanaclasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antanaclasis)**: the word newspaper is only used once, but with two meanings.
- **[Pun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun)**: pun's generally rely on two different interpretations of the word, separately to give the sentence two possible meanings. Not at the same same time to give the sentence 1 meaning (also they tend to be funny)

Comment: (+1) The only comparable sentence I can come up with is 'I was going to dust but there wasn't any'. The hinge word is a kind of 'fused homonym'.

Comment: @NigelJ that one is even most unusual, not only does is the word using two word-senses, it is using two different parts of speech! I'll add it to the question since it is really interesting, and so it won't get lost in the comments

Comment: 'Dust' is an antonym. Its meanings are contradictory. _To dust_ means to eliminate dust.

Comment: You’re looking for ***polysemy***. You might also be interested in *structural ambiguity*, which is a different concept but related to your “dust” example. In re @NigelJ ‘s “meanings are contradictory”, the key term there is *contranym*.

Comment: @DanBron Polyseme is on my list of "Terms i have already considered and that are not correct for describing this". Would you care to explain why my reasoning is wrong for discount it?

Comment: Polysemy applies to any word which exhibits different meanings. Here you have a couple examples of words exhibiting different meanings. Hence the topic covering the examples is polysemy. There might be a more specific hyponym of polysemy which covers on this “simultaneous polysemy” or superposition of meanings or whatever, but it would still be in the polysemy chapter of a NLP textbook (for example).

Comment: @DanBron My motivation for wanting to know more about it, is that I have yet to see a NLP WSD method that has been able to handle such cases (I'ld love to be proved wrong). Or that has even acknowledged that they exist. Manning and Schütze's "Foundations of Statistical Language Processing" comes close to talking about it (where they talk about co-activation, and ambiguities) though I am not sure they are talking about this precise case, and they don't present methods to directly handle it. I'ld be interested to know of a polysemy chapter of a NLP textbook treats it better/in more detail.

Comment: Your newspaper example sentence actually need not be an example. One can refer to reading a newspaper in the sense of the company/publisher/whatever-appropriate-term. (E.g., "I read the New York Times.")

Comment: @jpmc26 I was thinking similarly, but change the verb from "reading" to "holding" and it becomes an example.

Comment: If you're interested in how NLP deals with homonyms/homophones you should check out this paper on "the buffalo sentence": https://www.cse.buffalo.edu//~rapaport/buffalobuffalo.html](https://www.cse.buffalo.edu//~rapaport/buffalobuffalo.html)

Comment: There's a book called [*7 Types of **Ambiguity***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Types_of_Ambiguity) that includes this as one type. Of course that's the word the author chose, which doesn't mean it's the best word.

Comment: John did not work for the newspaper, he worked for the company that PUBLISHES the newspaper.

Comment: @Dave I say all the time "I used to work for the bank", My grandfather, did work for a "company that publishes the newspaper.", and he says all the time "I used to work for the newspaper.".   This usage is commonly understood by all people I've spoken to. Where a company  is referred to as its most important services/product

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you're referring to the term *zeugma*.

> **zeugma** *noun*
>   A figure of speech in which a word applies to two others in different senses (e.g. John and his driving licence expired last week).
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/zeugma)

The dictionary entry also references the term *syllepsis*:

> **syllepsis** *noun*
>   A figure of speech in which a word is applied to two others of which it grammatically suits only one (e.g. neither they nor it is working).
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/syllepsis)

Both terms are referenced in the following entry:

> In rhetoric, zeugma (/ˈzuːɡmə/ ... or /ˈzjuːɡmə/; from the Ancient Greek ζεῦγμα, zeûgma, lit. "a yoking together") and syllepsis (/sɪˈlɛpsɪs/; from the Ancient Greek σύλληψις, sullēpsis, lit. "a taking together") are figures of speech in which one single phrase or word joins different parts of a sentence.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis)

Here are a couple of examples from [yourdictionary.com](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-zeugma.html):

- "The farmers in the valley grew potatoes, peanuts, and bored." (Wunderland)
- "She opened her door and her heart to the orphan." (Wunderland)

Comment: Yes, it must be that.  As such, it is more a figure of speech than a feature of grammar.  I would put my money on syllepsis.  I think of zeugma as often used for humour:  “she went out in her raincoat and gales of laughter.”

Answer (score 5):

The first example of the OP 'newspaper' is further defined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis) as a 'semantic syllepsis'. The article also lists four types of Zeugma; then a Diazeugma, a Hypozeugma, a Prozeugma and a Mesozeugma - thrilling stuff.

> Zeugma (often also called syllepsis, or **semantic syllepsis**): a single word is used with two other parts of a sentence but must be understood differently in relation to each.

Example: "He took his hat and his leave."

---

My second example 'dust' might be cheating, I am not sure; because the second mention of dust is an ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind, the example sentence illustrates synecdoche...

**synecdoche** (n). A figure of speech in which a part is used to represent the whole (The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, 3rd ed., 1992)

...because the physical newspaper is being used to represent the entire organization that produces it.