# what is the meaning of "flux"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the present case, we knew that collaboration would be a key theme, so we entered into the construction of this volume with the
meta-issues not only in mind, but also in flux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the ordinary meaning of *flux*. I'd attribute the odd turn of phrase to [zeugma](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/415412/142322).

> **flux** *noun*
>   3 (mass noun) Continuous change.
>   ‘since the fall of the wall Berlin has been a city in flux’
>   ‘the whole political system is in a state of flux’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/flux)

The quote says that because they knew the topic of collaboration was important, they started with the meta-issues in mind ... and because collaboration was important, they started with the assumption that the meta-issues weren't fixed. Presumably, the meta-issues would need to be sorted out via collaboration.